# Setting the width of a pagination depending on how many child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to set the width of a pagination depending on how many child elements are available.

The reasoning for this, is because I want to centralise it within a parent div element.

At the moment, I've resorted to trying to find the outerWidth of the UL element and setting the css to mirror this, but that still wont work.

Any ideas?

http://jsbin.com/ezaqax/edit#javascript,html

Answer (score 0):

You don't need javascript for this, just CSS:

```
div {
    width:415px;
    border:2px solid red; 
    text-align: center
}
ul {
    margin-top:20px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0;
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/ezaqax/4/edit

Was there a reason you had an empty `ol` in the middle of the `li`? Also, you have some invalid `li` elements which aren't contained in a parent `ul` or `ol`.

Comment: Hi Rory ... thanks for coming back to me .... Unfortunately I can't because I have other elements within the div which won't be centralised.

Comment: Can you please post the full HTML in your example.

Comment: Also thanks for the heads up with regards to the invalid elements .... its code which is being dynamically generated via a plugin